# Run script on specific file in all subdirs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I've written a script (foo) which makes a simple sed replacement on text in the input file. I have a directory (a) containing a large number of subdirectories (a/b1, a/b2 etc) which all have the same subdirs (c, etc) and contain a file with the same name (d). So the rough structure is:

```
a/
-b1/
--c/
---d
-b2/
--c/
---d
-b3/
--c/
---d
```

I want to run my script on every file (d) in the tree. Unfortunately the following doesn't work:

```
sudo sh foo a/*/c/d
```

how do I use wildcards in a bash command like this? Do I have to use `find` with specific max and mindepth, or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Indeed, looks like find is your friend

Comment: Do you use `sh` or `bash`?

Comment: if your bash version supports, you can set `shopt -s globstar` and then try `ls **/d` if it matches what you need... than you can use `sudo sh foo **/d` .. see [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29) for more info... also note that `sh` may not be same as `bash`

Comment: @Sundeep `sh` *is not* the same as `bash`; it might be a link to or copy of `bash`, but `bash` behaves differently when invoked as `sh`.

Comment: @chepner just to be clear, even if `sh` and `bash` pointed to same thing, behavior is different when shebang is `sh`? I didn't know that...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard expansion in your example should work, and no find should be needed.  I assume a b and c are just some generic file names to simplify the question. Do any of your folders/files contain spaces?

If you do:

```
ls -l a/*/d/c
```

are you getting the files you need listed? If so, then it is how you handle the `$*` in your script file. Mind sharing it with us?

As you can see, wildcard expansion works

```
$ ls -l a/*/c/d
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel  0 15 Apr 08:05 a/b1/c/d
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel  0 15 Apr 08:05 a/b2/c/d
-rw-r--r--  1 user  wheel  0 15 Apr 08:05 a/b3/c/d
```

Comment: So it does, thanks! In my script I was just using $1, so only addressing the first file in the list. Changing it to $@ did the trick. Here is the final script: `#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    filenames=$@
else
        filenames="./d"
fi
sed -i '<REGEXP>' $filenames`